# Did two LEFT JOIN used to produce a cartesian product?

Tags: mysql, anti-patterns

I am reading the book *SQL Antipattern* from *Bill Karwin*. In Chapter 18 he discusses a bad complex query on this example:

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
COUNT(f.bug_id) AS count_fixed, 
COUNT(o.bug_id) as count_open 
FROM BugsProducts p
LEFT Outer JOIN (BugsProducts bpf JOIN Bugs f Using (bug_id))
   ON (p.bug_id = f.bug_id AND f.status = 'FIXED')
LEFT OUTER JOIN (BugsProducts bpo JOIN Bugs o Using (bug_id)) 
   ON (p.bug_id = o.bug_id AND o.status = 'OPEN')
WHERE p.product_id = 1
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

He claims the following:

> You happen to know that in reality there are eleven fixed bugs and
>   seven open bugs for the given product. So the Result of the query is
>   puzzeling:
>
> ```
> product_id | count_fixed | count_open 
>     1      |    77       |     77
> ```

Its then explained that this happens because the result is the cartesian product between fixed and open bugs.

I did not understand why this should happen and I rebuild-ed this query with MySQL 5.7.25.

The result was surprisingly

```
product_id | count_fixed | count_open 
    1      |    11       |     7
```

Also one can simply replace `(BugsProducts bpf JOIN Bugs f Using (bug_id))` with `Bugs f` and `(BugsProducts bpf JOIN Bugs o Using (bug_id))` with `Bugs o`.

Why is it claimed that the query should do a cartesian product? Is the query only returning the 11/7 result because of some specialty in MySQL that would not work in other DB's?

Comment: @billkarwin Any thoughts?

Comment: My 3 pences: **1.** There shouldn't be a cartesian product here because the tables _looks_ properly joined on their PK/FK. **2.** this mix between ON and USING syntax is horrible (but maybe it was the point as it is a book talking about _bad complexity_). **3.** There's no need to join the Bugs tables  at  all (inside the jointures) because no data are retrieved from them and the ultimate aim is only to count the NOT NULL `bug_id` in both joined tables. Wondering what the book author will say, if he answers the call above...

Comment: @ThomasG I finished the chapter and the autor also addresses **2.** and **3.**. It was part of the bad example he wanted to fix. However, still not sure about **1.**

Answer (score 1):

Two left join can produce a Cartesian product occasionally.

In this case, the query does not make sense at all. Most probable is that it is a mistake.

Try to remove `GROUP BY p.product_id` and change the select clause as:

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
f.bug_id AS bug1Id, 
o.bug_id as bug2Id
```

This way, it is more obvious what is the result set.

I assume we have the following tables:

- Products(product_id)
- Bugs(bug_id, status)
- BugsProducts(bug_id, product_id)

where BugsProducts is the join table between Products and Bugs

With the query, it is trying to

- get all BugsProducts (p) rows for product_id = 1
- joined 1st with (BugsProducts - Bugs inner join) with same **bug_id** as (p), so joining each row of BugsProducts to itself and also Bugs table **if status = 'FIXED'**, so to summarize if the bug row has status = 'FIXED', it is joined to p(which is to itself), otherwise no row is joined (you see NULL to bug1Id)
- same with the 2nd join but with condition status = 'OPEN'

Anyway, I believe what the author wanted to demonstrate is something like:

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
COUNT(f.bug_id) AS count_fixed, 
COUNT(o.bug_id) as count_open 
FROM Products p
LEFT Outer JOIN (BugsProducts bpf JOIN Bugs f Using (bug_id))
   ON (bpf.product_id = p.product_id AND f.status = 'FIXED')
LEFT OUTER JOIN (BugsProducts bpo JOIN Bugs o Using (bug_id)) 
   ON (bpo.product_id = p.product_id AND o.status = 'OPEN')
WHERE p.product_id = 1
Group by p.product_id
```

which results in a Cartesian product.